# How to show SSR errors in next.js to users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using next.js app router at version v14.0.3
In my app i have pages that might generate errors during ssr fetching of another api, i want to be able to show the user errors based off what happened, for example when a 403/401 error appears i want to be able to tell the user to login/they can't access the route.

Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to do this "easily" or in a way that doesn't involve 10 if check and try catches in every single route, i had planned to create an abstraction over the api by returning a "result" type similar to rust, where in the error there is a parsed error that includes the reason, status code and more info that i can show the user, but then how do i propagate it back to the user? What's the proper way to do this?

Currently in next.js the error is "stripped" when sent back to the user for "security reasons" which i guess make sense, but then what would the alternative be?